# Created programmatically button isn't react on click

Tags: android, button

I create programmatically button (buttonDynamic1) to exist layout. Button is created and when I click on this button it should turn on DatePicker but nothing happens. I don't know where is error.

Thanks for help.

```
    //other code

   private Button buttonDynamic1;

//other code


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //other code

            rLayout = (RelativeLayout)  findViewById(R.id.rlayout);
            lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    buttonDynamic1 = new Button(this);

    //other code

    }

    ///other code

 private OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1){
            buttonDynamic1.setOnClickListener(this);


            buttonDynamic1.setId(1);
            buttonDynamic1.setText("BUTTON");

            lprams.setMargins(0, 100, 0, 0);
            lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.button1);
            lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.view);
            lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, R.id.button1);
            buttonDynamic1.setLayoutParams(lprams);
            buttonDynamic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.color1);

            rLayout.addView(buttonDynamic1);

            if (v.getId() == buttonDynamic1.getId() ){
                  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                buttonDynamic1.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                dpd.show();

            }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: You forgot to assign your listener to your Button. You can do it in this way: `buttonDynamic1.setOnClickListener(yourListener)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not setting click listener to your button. try this :

```
buttonDynamic1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {





                  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                buttonDynamic1.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                dpd.show();


        }


});
```

Comment: sorry for that. I just edited my code. my mistake with copy-paste original code.

Comment: ok, work. I deleted "if (v.getId() == buttonDynamic1.getId())" and paste your code and work.

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't attach the listener to the button:

```
buttonDynamic1 = new Button(this);
buttonDynamic1.setOnClickListener(l); <====
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add listener to your button. Like this:

```
buttonDynamic1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //your code
    }
});
```

or using your `l` listener:

```
buttonDynamic1.setOnClickListener(l);
```

Answer (score 0):

First You have to add an ID for Your button like this:#

```
 buttonDynamic1 = new Button(this);
 buttonDynamic1.setId(YourPositiveIntegerValue);
```

Then set it on Click:

```
 buttonDynamic1.setOnClickListener(l);
```

Don´t do it inside Your onClick from the other button. You have not finished the method from it:

```
   if (v.getId() == R.id.button1){
        buttonDynamic1.setOnClickListener(this);


        buttonDynamic1.setId(1);
        buttonDynamic1.setText("BUTTON");

        lprams.setMargins(0, 100, 0, 0);
        lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.button1);
        lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.view);
        lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, R.id.button1);
        buttonDynamic1.setLayoutParams(lprams);
        buttonDynamic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.color1);

        rLayout.addView(buttonDynamic1);

       } //You have forgot to close onClick from button1, make a claim
        //You need to finish the onClick from Your other button first...
        if (v.getId() == buttonDynamic1.getId() ){
```

So what happens is, that You write this code inside the onClick from button1 and then it could never be reached.